# In react-redux the state change value is not applied in real time

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

loginRequest

```
const handleLogin = (id, pw) => {
    return props.loginRequest(id, pw).then(
              console.log(props.status);
           )
}
```

actions

```
/* LOGIN */
export function loginRequest(username, password) {
    return (dispatch) => {
        dispatch(login());

        //API
        return axios.post('http://localhost:8080/api/user/login', {username, password})
        .then(response => {
            var result = response && response.data;

            if(result.success == true) {
                dispatch(loginSuccess(username, result.token));
            } else {
                dispatch(loginFailure());
            }
        })
        .catch(response => {
            //logging 처리 필요
            console.log(response);
        });
    };
}
```

reducers

```
const initialState = {
    login: {
        status: 'INIT',
    },
    register: {
        status: 'INIT',
        error: -1
    },
    status: {
        valid: false,
        isLoggedIn: false,
        currentUser: '',
        user: {},
        token: ''
    }
};

        /* LOGIN */
        case types.AUTH_LOGIN:
          return {
            ...state,
            login: {
              status: 'WAITING'
            },
          }
        case types.AUTH_LOGIN_SUCCESS:
          return {
            ...state,
            login: {
              status: 'SUCCESS',
            },
            status: {
              ...state.status,
              isLoggedIn: true,
              currentUser: action.username,
              token : action.token
            }
          }
        case types.AUTH_LOGIN_FAILURE:
          return {
            ...state,
            login: {
              status: 'FAILURE'
            }
          }
        default:
          return state;
      }
```

index.js

```
const hist = createBrowserHistory();
const store = createStore(reducers, applyMiddleware(thunk));
ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <Router history={hist}>
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/rtl" component={RtlLayout} />
        <Route path="/auth" component={AuthLayout} />
        <Route path="/admin" component={AdminLayout} />
        <Redirect from="/" to="/admin/dashboard" />
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

[image]

Hello

I have implemented the login module above.

If id and pw values are exceeded, the API checks the membership and returns the success and token information.

The problem is that when we call loginrequest we change the state value with dispatch ().
This doesn't apply in real time.

One beat is applied slowly.

Sending success from the server API doesn't take effect immediately and redux has INIT.

When the second run is executed, success is applied and success is returned.

What's wrong with the code above?

Comment: Its done asynchronously. Just like states, you're not going to see the change in state if you console log right after

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite see what the issue is?
Is the problem that you call `loginRequest()` and

```
var result = response && response.data;

if(result.success == true) {
    dispatch(loginSuccess(username, result.token));
} else {
    dispatch(loginFailure());
}
```

doesn't run immediately?

If so, that would be expected as you are making an async call to the api.

Comment: It is not updated immediately.

No problem when used in class components,
There is a problem when used in function components.

It seems to be due to differences in the generation cycle.

You should get success when you execute the login request

INIT is returned.

Comment: What is not updated immediately?
When you say 'execute the login request' are you referring to the entire `loginRequest` function or just `dispatch(login())`?
Are you saying the expected behaviour is to get 'success' but you are getting 'INIT'?

Comment: Yes that's right. The desired behavior is success.
But returns INIT

Comment: I think I understand what you mean now. The first time you call `handleLogin` the value of props.status will be INIT, this is because you created initial state to be this. Even after the call to `loginRequest` resolves, it still has the 'old' props, so will console.log INIT.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you're looking at output from

```
const handleLogin = (id, pw) => {
    return props.loginRequest(id, pw).then(
              console.log(props.status);
           )
}
```

And as `console.log` uses `props` it is inside some component.

When component holding `handleLogin` is rendered it accepts `props`. These `props` are just object that will stay the same during one rendering cycle of the component. So when `loginRequest` will be finished, you're seeing `porps` that has been passed when `loginRequest` has been called. When `props` will be changed, React will re-render component with updated props. So if you want to monitor props, you have to call `console.log` from component itself like this

```
const SomeComponent = props => {
    console.log(props.status);

    const handleLogin = (id, pw) => {
        return props.loginRequest(id, pw).then(
            console.log(props.status);
        )
    }

    return <div/>
}
```

Also you have error in `then`. It accepts function which will be executed when promise will be resolved. The correct usage is

```
.then(() => console.log(props.status))
```

But on it own, modifying syntax will not solve your issue. Just call to `console.log` will be executed when promise will be resolved.